# Filter based on results where ROW_NUMBER goes higher than 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, filtering, row-number

I've managed to get some ordered results using `ROW_NUMBER()` and partitioned by the Country code and client ref, ordered by the date of the quote. The `ROW_NUMBER()` column is called PRank.

```
CountryCode  ¦   ClientRef   ¦   Quote Ref   ¦   Name     ¦    Address     ¦   PostCode   ¦   PreferencesCode   ¦   QuoteDate         ¦   PolicyType   ¦   PRank   ¦
     0           AABB001         AABB001MB1    Mr A Smith   1 Country Lane     WA21 2PU       5934611             2017-03-18 00:00:00     MB               1
     0           AABB001         AABBMM1MB2    Mr A Smith   1 Country Lane     WA21 2PU       5934611             2017-03-18 00:00:00     MB               2
     0           AABB001         AABBMM1MB3    Mr A Smith   1 Country Lane     WA21 2PU       5934611             2017-03-18 00:00:00     MB               3
     0           BBGG003         BBGG003MB1    Mrs B Jones  2 City Road        M1 3XY         312191              2017-09-02 00:00:00     MB               1
```

This is the code for my `ROW_NUMBER()` column:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CountryCode, ClientRef, QuoteDate 
                  ORDER BY QuoteDate DESC, PolicyRef asc)
```

There are a lot of results like the last row; they only count to 1 because the customer just had one quote on the date in question. I want to eliminate those rows without removing any rows from the customer results where multiple quotes occured on the same date (i.e. I still want to see all three rows of the first customer in the results above) so I figured by using a CTE and filtering on the ROW_NUMBER would cause me to lose data from the results that I still need to see.

I was trying to do something with HAVING and summing the PRank column but I couldn't figure out the grouping as I don't want to actually aggregate the data, just get rid of any rows where a ClientRef only has one QuoteRef per day.

Comment: Insert current result set into temporary table, then delete those where `having count(*) = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for customers with more than 1 quote in a day the a CTE would still be the best way to go.

Assuming this is against the `ic_dapolicy` view in InfocentrePlus (this is obviously OpenGI data, and the icp tables aren't as easy to use) then you're query would be something like:

```
WITH Quotes AS(
    SELECT *,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY PPY.B@, PPY.Ref@) AS ClientQuotes 
    FROM ic_Dapolicy PPY
    WHERE PPY.Quote_date = @Quote_date) --If you aren't filtering on Quote_date in your where, add it to the PARTITION BY clause
SELECT [YourColumns]
FROM Quotes
WHERE ClientQuotes > 1;
```

Comment: Yes! That was what I'd forgotten about, aggregating with the PARTITION function. Ugh. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like the following.

```
;WITH Rankings AS
(
    -- Your query here
    SELECT
        CountryCode = 1,
        ClientRef = 1,
        QuoteDate = 1,
        PRank = 1
),
Only1Record AS
(
    SELECT
        R.CountryCode, 
        R.ClientRef, 
        R.QuoteDate
    FROM
        Rankings AS R
    GROUP BY
        R.CountryCode, 
        R.ClientRef, 
        R.QuoteDate
    HAVING
        MAX(R.PRank) = 1
)
DELETE D FROM
    Only1Record AS R
    INNER JOIN Rankings AS D ON
        R.CountryCode = D.CountryCode AND
        R.ClientRef = D.ClientRef AND
        R.QuoteDate = D.QuoteDate
```

Another more simple variation is using a windowed `COUNT()`.

```
;WITH Rankings AS
(
    -- Your query here
    SELECT
        CountryCode = 1,
        ClientRef = 1,
        QuoteDate = 1,
        PRank = 1,
        Total = COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY CountryCode, ClientRef, QuoteDate)
)
DELETE D FROM
    Rankings AS D
WHERE
    D.Total = 1
```